# Install 32-bit support libraries before Android Studio will run

Tags: linux, android-studio, 64-bit, android-studio-3.0, 32-bit

Source: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/linux-32-bit-libraries

When we running Android Studio on Linux `64-bit` system,  it will be necessary to install some `32-bit` support libraries, before Android Studio will run.

On Ubuntu these libraries can be installed using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1 libbz2-1.0:i386
```

On RedHat and Fedora-based 64-bit systems, use the following command:

```
sudo yum install zlib.i686 ncurses-libs.i686 bzip2-libs.i686
```

My misunderstanding about this, I want to know, why it will be necessary to install some
32-bit support libraries? What is the purpose of that?

Comment: Hi, have you figured this out yet?